# Problem with infinitely looping text in a word generator

Tags: java

I'm making a Palindrome Generator.  Basically the user inputs a word or sentence and the program outputs whether or not its a Palindrome, which is a word that is spelled the same forwards and backwards like "wow" or "racecar".  My program works fine, however the output text will repeat itself like fifty times and I can't seem to figure out where the issue is without messing everything up.  Help would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class palindromedectector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String testStrings = "";
           testStrings = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter word: ");
        
    for (int i = 0; i < testStrings.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print("\"" + testStrings + "\"");
        if (isPalindrome(stripString(testStrings)))
        System.out.println(" is a palindrome.");
        else
        System.out.println(" is not a palindrome.");
    }   
}

    public static String stripString(String strip)
    {
        strip = strip.toUpperCase();
        String stripped= "";
        for (int i= 0; i< strip.length(); i++)
        {
        if (Character.isLetter(strip.charAt(i)))
            stripped += strip.charAt(i);
        }
        return stripped;
        }
    
    
    public static boolean isPalindrome (String str)
    {
        boolean status = false;
        if (str.length() <= 1)
            status = true;
        else if (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(str.length()-1))
        {
            status = isPalindrome (str.substring(1, str.length()-1));
        }
        return status;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You only need to call `isPalindrome` once from `main`, not in a loop.

Comment: It's a good example for recursion, but keep in mind #substring will make new string references, and if you had an excessively long string (millions of characters), you could potentially exceed the limits of your stack size. I would recommend a loop here if you're looking for performance

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that you run `isPalindrome` check for the same string in the loop, probably you wanted to run multiple checks

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int attempts = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
        String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter word: ");

        System.out.print("\"" + word + "\"");
        if (isPalindrome(stripString(word))) {
            System.out.println(" is a palindrome.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" is not a palindrome.");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the main functionality may be implemented in a shorter way:

```java
// use regexp to get rid of non-letters
private static String stripString(String word) {
    if (null == word || word.isEmpty()) {
        return word;
    }
    return word.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").toUpperCase(); // remove all non-letters
}

// use Java Stream API to check letters using half of word length
private static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    if (null == word) {
        return false;
    }
    final int len = word.length();
    if (len < 2) {
        return true;
    }
    return IntStream.range(0, len/2)
                    .allMatch(i -> word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(len - 1 - i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem: You are testing if the word is a palindrome `testStrings.length()` times, ie once for *every letter* in the word, rather than just once.

Remove the `for` loop in your `main()` method.